# Powershell Results to Slack via Webhook question - Remote Server results

Tags: powershell, slack

I need a bit of help as I couldn't find an answear on the open topics related to how exactly to send the powershell results to a slack channel.

For a bit of context, I'm remoting to a server trying to get different information like read some files or status of services and instead of sending an email with the resutls I thought it will be good to post the results directly to a slack channel.

I tried the following simple command, but I'm missing something on how posting to slack channel via webhook app works.

```
$Results = Get-Service Service* -ComputerName 
Send-SlackMessage -Uri <webhook URI> -Text $Results
```

The above scripts doesn't work unfortunatlly.
Would you be able to help me understand how exactly the slack message function should be setup in orde to send the results from powershell to the slack channel?

Thank you!
M

Comment: I think you should start by checking Names & Member types by running - 'get-service | get-member | sort Name'. Then attempt '$Results = Get-Service -Name *App* | Select Name' as a test. In the new version of PowerShell '-ComputerName' is not available.

Comment: The -ComputerName part I use to get the service status from a remote server. Or that can't work with slack api?

Comment: depends on the version of PowerShell. In version 5 yes and in version 7.2 no. This is by design. The Get-Service command made use of DCOM and such functionality is removed in PowerShell 7. To work around your issuse try '$Results = Invoke-Command -Computername 'servername' -Scriptblock {Get-Service}'

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll definetly try this out!

Comment: np. When you've confirmed, if you could please mark this post as answered. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

**Differences between Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x**
Please Note In Windows 7.2 the Get-Service command made use of DCOM and such functionality like '-ComputerName' is removed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7#remove--computername-from--service-cmdlets-5090

```
$server = $env:Computername
Invoke-Command -Computername $server -Scriptblock {Get-Service | where status -eq 'started;}
```

A simple function to send messages to Slack can be found here -

**PowerShell and a Slack API Webhook**

https://mufana.github.io/blog/2018/04/13/PoshSlackHook

**Get-Service cmdlet**

The cmdlet gets the members, the properties and methods, of objects

```
get-service | get-member | sort Name
```

Names of services that start / contain 'App'

```
$Results = Get-Service -Name App | Select Name
```