# Powershell to query specific Service in enterprise?

Tags: powershell

Good day good people.

Would someone please help me out I am trying to PS our enterprise servers to find all assets with a particular service on it and having no luck.

I tried

```
$servicename = "SERVICE_NAME"
$list = get-content "c:\security\comp_list.txt"
foreach ($server in $list) {
    if (Get-Service $servicename -computername $server -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'){
    Write-Host "$servicename exists on $server
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm still fairly new to PS.

Comment: Ideally, you would need to remove the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and add to your question the actual error you're getting.

Comment: “*having no luck*” tells us absolutely nothing that can help you. What *does* happen? Why are you **hiding** errors?

Comment: I know why this fails. The **Get-Service** cmdlet does **not** have **'-computername'**option. You need to use an **Invoke-Command** method to get service information from **remote computers**. Solution provided here <https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/89170e92-47c1-4c0c-be49-0a3141333b87/getservice-from-a-remote-machine>

Answer (score 0):

My accepted answer to why **Get-Service -ComputerName** fails can be found in the link below and the resolution to the issue.

[Powershell Results to Slack via Webhook question - Remote Server results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224774/powershell-results-to-slack-via-webhook-question-remote-server-results/70225091#70225091)

**Summary**

**Differences between Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x**
Please Note In Windows 7.2 the Get-Service command made use of DCOM and such functionality like '-ComputerName' is removed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7#remove--computername-from--service-cmdlets-5090

```
$server = $env:Computername
Invoke-Command -Computername $server -Scriptblock {Get-Service | where status -eq 'started;}
```

**Get-Service cmdlet**

The cmdlet gets the members, the properties and methods, of objects

```
get-service | get-member | sort Name
```

Names of services that start / contain 'App'

```
$Results = Get-Service -Name App | Select Name
```